# What is the XPath to Discord's input box?

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to use Selenium in order to send messages through Discord, but I have not managed to find the right XPath for the input box.
I've tried XPaths such as `'/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/main/form/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div'` and other examples from past threads but they either don't work or are outdated.

Does anyone know the current XPath?

Comment: Any source web page ? Or real HTML ?

Comment: Can't really link any web page more specific than https://discord.com/ since it would just require you to sign in. I'm talking about the input box in any channel/server.

Comment: You can copy the html part that you try to scrape. No one I think will open an account especially to test

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox: right click on the input field → inspect → in the inspector's HTML tree, find the div that has role='textbox' (and all the other attributes that suggest it is editable, I didn't know which one I just guessed) → right click → copy → xpath.

I didn't try it in Chromium or other browsers but I suppose there's a similar way to do it.

Atm of writing this seems to be:

`/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/main/form/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]`